# "Unable to open the [test name] test." message when starting QTP autotest from QC

Tags: quality-center, qtp, hp-alm, qtp-11.0, hp-alm-12.20

I am integrating QTP 11.0 autotests with HP ALM 12.20 so I could run them directly from ALM. So I've done everything according to [Quality Center - QC-QTP Integration](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qc/qtp_qc_integration.htm):

- installed QuickTest_Add-in_for_ALM-QC
- set up HP ALM connection to QC
- saved the test in Quality Center Test Plan
- added Test Resources (Shared Object Repositories, libraries)
- added Test to the Test Lab and executed test

But the problem I've got when starting test from HP ALM's test lab is:

[image]

BTW: there was a time when the test executed once, but then the problem came back again.

Also tried:

- grant access to everyone to the user temp area (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp)

Does anyone know what to do?

**Extra questions / info to clear up things:**

1. Can you open test files using QTP from ALM/QC Test Plan (as for me, after 'Save as' operation, I am trying to open the file and I've got the message `"Test [test name] does not exist"`)
2. In Test Plan on the tab Test Script of the autotest the message is shown `"Can't load test from C:\Users\\[user]\AppData\Local\Temp\TD_80\87\6732cc74\Test\1107\1107\1107"`, but still when I close it there is a kind of test structure displayed in `Keyword View`. But when I open this path from QTP everything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to check a option in QTP in your machine, which says allow all HP users to run ALM somthing.

That can be one reason of this error!

try it once.
Also, please clarify if you are using BPT framework in QTP of ALM implementation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using UFT, go into Options > GUI Testing, and check off the box that says "Allow HP products to run tests and components".